# What can I do to make YouTube work properly?

Tags: youtube

Slow buffering and missing quality options.

[image]

Also, if I want to go back to a section of the video I already buffered it will buffer the video again.

I've already tried different browsers and different PCs, so my guess is it has something to do with my ISP. Other streaming sites like Twitch work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You may want check out this link: 
[Force YouTube to always buffer the entire video before playing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23671/force-youtube-to-always-buffer-the-entire-video-before-playing/30612#30612?newreg=533974ee1d60471592d431e89ba6377e)

Below in the comment section there are valuable choices; for example you can download the app that sets the quality as your own default.( 360p, 480p, etc.)

Also, lowering the quality to 360p or 480, depending on the size of the video, it will be likely to buffer the video, and you can hereafter scroll back and forth in the video.